# Swift 3 pass button/gesture recognizer action to other function using selector

Tags: swift3

I am having a problem with Swift 3 action selectors - or, I can say, with gesture recognizers.

Suppose I am in a table view where I am having dynamic data through a table cell. I have one button or gesture recogniser in the table view and I want to send data from that button or gesture to a different function.

Comment: Please try to add some code and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try the below function, Hope it will work for you!!**

```
func whereYouWant(){

let button = UIButton()
button.accessibilityElements = [data1,data2]//Here you can pass any thing in this array.

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testFunction), for: .touchUpInside)
}


//Here you can call this function through selector....

func testFunction(myButton:UIButton){

let firstData = myButton.accessibilityElements?[0] as? //Here you can do type cast According to you

let secondData =   myButton.accessibilityElements?[1] as? //Here you can do type Cast According to you.


}
```

Comment: Thanks brother, it's really worked for me in both the case gesture recogniser as well as in button, as you have described above.